# Is there a usable GUI version of Photorec or Testdisk?

Tags: data-recovery

I wanted to recover some files from my sd card with Photorec, everything went fine, I use Ubuntu for a few years now, so I've seen the terminal quite a few times.

But, I wondered if a GUI version of Photorec exists. Is there any? If yes, how to install it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8):

[`qphotorec`](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/QPhotoRec?content=162293)

[image]

It is not available via any repository. Installation:

```
wget -c https://versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/crunchyiconthem/QPhotoRec/qphotorec_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i qphotorec_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Mind you: when restoring data it is best to NOT touch the system you want it recovered from. Installing software on a system that you want files recovered from should be avoided.

Comment: After following the installation progress I can search for QPhotorec in the dash. After clicking on the application a window opened up "QPhotorec is not yet production ready!
This Beta version is included in Parted Magic for testing purposes." Nothing else opens. I can't get to the window shown above. Any ideas?

Comment: `qphotorec: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @NicNacDeluxe this problem solved in https://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=13365.0